# How to add a few seconds of gap between looped audio in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to loop a voice.mp3 in FFmpeg. And it is looping successfully with the stram_loop X command.
But the problem is it's looping breathless. How can I add a few seconds of silence between loops?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create a padded version and loop that.

```
ffmpeg -i voice.mp3 -af apad=pad_dur=2.0 padded.mp3
```

and then

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop X -i padded.mp3 ...
```